# Get full name based on username for 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for an output like:

```
|  BOOK |        ANALYST |         SUPERVISOR |
|-------|----------------|--------------------|
| BookA |         (null) |         Dani Sant  |
| BookB |         (null) |  North Andre Miles |
| BookC |    Andrea Plus |        Andrea Plus |
| BookD | Jeff Dron Math |     Jeff Dron Math |
| BookE |   Theo Phillip |       Julian Rhode |
```

What I am getting is:

```
|  BOOK |        ANALYST |   SUPERVISOR |
|-------|----------------|--------------|
| BookA |         (null) |    dani.sant |
| BookB |         (null) |  north.miles |
| BookC |    Andrea Plus |  andrea.plus |
| BookD | Jeff Dron Math |    jeff.math |
| BookE |   Theo Phillip | julian.rhode |
```

I can do the join with one column, but when I try for both, the result isn't showing like it should. Thanks for any information on this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e29bf/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE books 
  (
    book varchar(10),
    analyst varchar(100),
    supervisor varchar(100)
  );

INSERT INTO books (book, analyst, supervisor)
VALUES
('BookA', NULL, 'dani.sant'),
('BookB', NULL, 'north.miles'),
('BookC', 'andrea.plus', 'andrea.plus'),
('BookD', 'jeff.math', 'jeff.math'),
('BookE', 'theo.phil', 'julian.rhode');

CREATE TABLE names 
  (
    username varchar(100),
    fullname varchar(500)
  );

INSERT INTO names (username, fullname)
VALUES
('dani.sant', 'Dani Sant'),
('north.miles', 'North Andre Miles'),
('andrea.plus', 'Andrea Plus'),
('jeff.math', 'Jeff Dron Math'),
('theo.phil', 'Theo Phillip'),
('julian.rhode', 'Julian Rhode');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    books.book AS Book,
    names.fullname AS Analyst,
    books.supervisor AS Supervisor
FROM
    books left join names on books.analyst = names.username
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e29bf/4/0)**:

```
|  BOOK |        ANALYST |   SUPERVISOR |
|-------|----------------|--------------|
| BookA |         (null) |    dani.sant |
| BookB |         (null) |  north.miles |
| BookC |    Andrea Plus |  andrea.plus |
| BookD | Jeff Dron Math |    jeff.math |
| BookE |   Theo Phillip | julian.rhode |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second `join` to the `names` table to get the supervisor's full name:

```
SELECT b.book AS Book, bn.fullname AS Analyst,
       sn.fullname AS Supervisor
FROM books b left join
     names bn
     on b.analyst = bn.username left join
     names sn
     on b.supervisor = sn.username;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will provide the output you desire.

```
 SELECT
        b.book AS Book,
        n.fullname AS Analyst,
        (SELECT fullname FROM names where username=b.Supervisor) AS Supervisor
    FROM
        books b left join names n on b.analyst = n.username
```